# 301 redirect on WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-301, redirect

After spending some time researching how to do this, I finally ended up with this `htaccess` file to redirect URLS from an old site (on same domain) to new design of site.

What's happening now is that when we visit some of these pages we're in an eternal redirect loop and not quite understanding where we might have gone wrong.

We've now removed the updated .htaccess file to get the site working but below are the redirects from the old URL's to the new URLs if someone could perhaps spot what might be wrong please?

**EDIT:**
After posting this, I noticed that some of the URL's are not closed off properly with a "
Other than that, does this the structure of this htaccess look correct?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^shop/checkout/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/cart/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/transaction-results/ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/checkout/order-received/"  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/your-account/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/my-account/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^faqs/vinyl-wall-sticker-information/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/vinyl-sticker-information/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/stockists/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/stockists/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/wholesale/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/wholesale/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/testimonials/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/testimonials/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/press/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/media/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^feed/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/feed/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/wall-art/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/framed-prints/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/wall-art/small-framed-prints/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/prints-on-canvas/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/wall-art/prints-on-canvas/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/wall-art/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/wall-art/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/jewellery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/jewellery/pendants/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/jewellery/lockets/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/stationery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/stationery/greeting-card-sets/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-1/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-1/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-3/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-3/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/dogs-flying-airplanes-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/dogs-flying-airplanes-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/little-boy-paper-boats-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/little-boy-paper-boats-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/bella-bear-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/bella-bear-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/kittens-and-butterflies-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/kittens-butterflies-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rita-rhino-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/rita-rhino-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-1/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-1/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-3/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-3/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-4/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-4/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-5/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-5/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/thinking-fairy-art-print-on-stretched-canvas/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/prints-on-canvas/thinking-fairy-art-print-stretched-canvas/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/sleeping-piglet-art-print-on-stretched-canvas/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/prints-on-canvas/sleeping-piglet-art-print-stretched-canvas/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/dragon-rider-art-print-on-stretched-canvas/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/prints-on-canvas/dragon-rider-art-print-stretched-canvas/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/windsock-height-chart-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/windsock-height-chart-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/dog-yellow-vintage-plane-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/dog-yellow-vintage-plane-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/green-banner-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/green-banner-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/decor/1597-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/dog-red-vintage-plane-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-5-vinyl-wall-stickers/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-5-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-4-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-4-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-3-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-3-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-2-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-2-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-1-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/kitten-1-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/bella-bear-1-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/bella-bear-1-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/bella-bear-2-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/bella-bear-2-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/bella-bear-3-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/bella-bear-3-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/little-boy-on-jetty-with-his-dog-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/little-boy-jetty-dog-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/paper-boat-2-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/paper-boat-2-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/paper-boat-3-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/paper-boat-3-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/paper-boat-4-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/paper-boat-4-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/lighthouse-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/lighthouse-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/blushing-bride-fairies-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/blushing-bride-fairies-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/thinking-fairy-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/kissing-fairies-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/kissing-fairies-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/fairies-in-love-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/fairies-love-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/princess-kissing-frog-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/little-girl-with-puppy-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/little-girl-puppy-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/piglet-with-umbrella-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/piglet-umbrella-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/thinking-fairy/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/kissing-fairies/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/kissing-fairies-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/fairies-in-love/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/jewellery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/princess-kissing-frog/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/little-girl-with-puppy/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/little-girl-puppy-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/spaniel-puppy/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/spaniel-puppy-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/piglet-with-umbrella/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/piglet-umbrella-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/25mm-pendant/sleeping-piglet/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/jewellery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/framed-prints/dragon-rider-framed-print/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-framed-prints/dragon-rider-framed-print/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/framed-prints/thinking-fairy-framed-print/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-framed-prints/thinking-fairy-framed-print/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/framed-prints/kissing-fairies-framed-print/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-framed-prints/kissing-fairies-framed-print/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/framed-prints/fairy-witchy-framed-print/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-framed-prints/fairy-witchy-framed-print/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/framed-prints/princess-kissing-frog-framed-print/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-framed-prints/princess-kissing-frog-framed-print/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/framed-prints/piglet-wearing-a-hat-framed-print/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-framed-prints/piglet-wearing-hat-framed-print/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/mixed-greeting-card-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/mixed-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/sleeping-piglet-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/sleeping-piglet-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/dragon-rider-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/dragon-rider-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/thinking-fairy-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/thinking-fairy-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/kissing-fairies-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/kissing-fairies-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/fairy-witchy-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/fairy-witchy-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/princess-kissing-frog-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/princess-kissing-frog-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/piglet-wearing-a-hat-greeting-card-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/piglet-wearing-hat-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/greeting-card-sets/piglet-with-umbrella-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/piglet-umbrella-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rabbit-wall-stickers-just-time-easter/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/rabbit-wall-stickers-just-time-easter/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/custom-nursery-design/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/custom-nursery-design/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/custom-nursery-design/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/illustration/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/illustration/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/vinyl-wall-art/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/vinyl-wall-art/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^catch-falling-star-magical-new-bunny-nursery-theme/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/catch-falling-star-magical-new-bunny-nursery-theme/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/fabric-with-illustrations/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/fabric-with-illustrations/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^four-temperaments-four-cute-south-african-creatures/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/four-temperaments-four-cute-south-african-creatures/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sensitive-child/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/sensitive-child/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^bunnies-catching-stars-nursery-decor-theme/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/bunnies-catching-stars-nursery-decor-theme/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/illustration/sketch-blog/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/sketch-blog/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rhino-wall-stickers-short-animation/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/rhino-wall-stickers-short-animation/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/fairy-caravan/animation/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/animation/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/fairy-caravan/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/fairy-caravan/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rita-rhinos-rhyme-new-wall-sticker-illustrations/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/rita-rhinos-rhyme-new-wall-sticker-illustrations/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^finding-inspiration-for-your-nursery-decor/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/finding-inspiration-for-your-nursery-decor/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/creativity/inspiration/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/inspiration/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products-now-stocked-by-kids-cove/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/products-now-stocked-by-kids-cove/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/art-prints/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/art-prints/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/fairy-caravan/stockists/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/stockists/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/fairy-caravan/studio-news/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/studio-news/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^happiness-seeing-wall-stickers-nursery/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/happiness-seeing-wall-stickers-nursery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fairy-caravan-in-ideas-magazine/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/fairy-caravan-in-ideas-magazine/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/fairy-caravan/press/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/press/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cms/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Ideas_March-2014-page80-web.pdf$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/files/2014/05/Ideas_March-2014-page80-web.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^valentines-day-free-printable-card-2014/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/valentines-day-free-printable-card-2014/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/illustration/drawing/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/drawing/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/childrens-stories/fairy/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/fairy/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/stationery/free-printable-download/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/free-printable-download/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/stationery/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/stationery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/stationery/valentines-day/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/valentines-day/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cms/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/2014-A6-Valentines-Day-mini-card.pdf$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/files/2014/05/2014-A6-Valentines-Day-mini-card.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fun-loving-child/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/fun-loving-child/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/childrens-stories/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/childrens-stories/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/prints-on-canvas/dragon-rider-art-print-on-stretched-canvas/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/prints-on-canvas/dragon-rider-art-print-stretched-canvas/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/prints-on-canvas/thinking-fairy-art-print-on-stretched-canvas/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/prints-on-canvas/thinking-fairy-art-print-stretched-canvas/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/prints-on-canvas/sleeping-piglet-art-print-on-stretched-canvas/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/prints-on-canvas/sleeping-piglet-art-print-stretched-canvas/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-3/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-3/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-1/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-1/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rabbit-wall-decal-bunny-catching-stars-2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-1/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-1/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-3/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-3/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-4/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-4/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-5/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/rita-rhino-vinyl-wall-sticker-5/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/windsock-height-chart-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/windsock-height-chart-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/dog-yellow-vintage-plane-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/dog-yellow-vintage-plane-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/green-banner-vinyl-wall-sticker/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/green-banner-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/vinyl-wall-stickers/1597-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/large-vinyl-wall-stickers/dog-red-vintage-plane-vinyl-wall-sticker/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/dogs-flying-airplanes-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/dogs-flying-airplanes-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/little-boy-paper-boats-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/little-boy-paper-boats-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/bella-bear-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/bella-bear-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/kittens-and-butterflies-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/kittens-butterflies-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/rita-rhino-small-vinyl-sticker-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/small-vinyl-sticker-sets/rita-rhino-small-vinyl-sticker-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/blushing-bride-fairies-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/blushing-bride-fairies-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/kissing-fairies-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/kissing-fairies-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/fairies-in-love-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/fairies-love-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/little-girl-with-puppy-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/little-girl-puppy-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/piglet-with-umbrella-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/piglet-umbrella-locket/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/kissing-fairies/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/kissing-fairies-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/fairies-in-love/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/jewellery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/little-girl-with-puppy/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/little-girl-puppy-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/spaniel-puppy/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/spaniel-puppy-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/piglet-with-umbrella/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/piglet-umbrella-pendant/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/sleeping-piglet/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/product-category/jewellery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/mixed-greeting-card-set/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/mixed-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/dragon-rider-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/dragon-rider-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/thinking-fairy-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/thinking-fairy-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/kissing-fairies-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/kissing-fairies-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/fairy-witchy-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/fairy-witchy-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/princess-kissing-frog-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/princess-kissing-frog-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/piglet-wearing-a-hat-greeting-card-2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/piglet-wearing-hat-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/stationery/piglet-with-umbrella-greeting-card/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/greeting-card-sets/piglet-umbrella-greeting-card-set/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^stimulating-childs-imagination-begins-nursery/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/stimulating-childs-imagination-begins-nursery/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/creativity/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/creativity/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^three-things-to-consider-when-choosing-nursery-decor/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/three-things-to-consider-when-choosing-nursery-decor/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^vintage-plane-illustrations/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/vintage-plane-illustrations/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/illustration/custom-illustration/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/custom-illustration/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cms/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dogs-flying-planes.pdf$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/files/2014/05/dogs-flying-planes.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cms/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dogs-flying-planes2.pdf$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/files/2014/05/dogs-flying-planes2.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/custom-nursery-design/page/2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/custom-nursery-design/page/2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/page/2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/custom-nursery-design/page/2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^work-progress-merry-meerkats/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/work-progress-merry-meerkats/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^special-festive-shopping-offer/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/special-festive-shopping-offer/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/fairy-caravan/special-offer/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/special-offer/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/illustration/page/2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/illustration/page/2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/nursery-decor/vinyl-wall-art/page/2/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/category/vinyl-wall-art/page/2/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^three-girl-mice-shopping/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/three-girl-mice-shopping/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/collaboration/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/2014/blog/category/collaboration/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^fairy-caravan-collaborates-with-peaches-handmade/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/fairy-caravan-collaborates-with-peaches-handmade/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mice-enjoying-wine-and-cheese/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/mice-enjoying-wine-and-cheese/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cms/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Shopping-mice-BW0002.pdf$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/files/2014/05/Shopping-mice-BW0002.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cms/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/wine-mice-BW0001.pdf$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/files/2014/05/wine-mice-BW0001.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^preview-kitten-nursery-theme/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/preview-kitten-nursery-theme/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^happy-to-be-back/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teddy-bear-with-umbrella-splashing-in-puddles/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/teddy-bear-with-umbrella-splashing-in-puddles/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^flying-teddy-bear-with-umbrella/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/blog/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Many thanks

Comment: As far as i read correctly some pages are redirecting to itself? (for example: `RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/thinking-fairy-locket/" [R=301,L]`) Could you give us an example old url & new url ?

Comment: Thanks Kristof, we'll remove those and test it. Add your reply as a possible answer and if it worked I will select your answer.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^shop/33mm-lockets/princess-kissing-frog-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-locket/" [R=301,L]`
`RewriteRule ^shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-locket/$ "http://fairycaravan.co.za/shop/jewellery/princess-kissing-frog-locket/" [R=301,L]`

Removing one of these lines seem to have it working